# How can I read All Items in table of table with lua api?

Tags: api, delphi, lua

I have a table in a lua file.

*This is the table:*

```
main = {}

main["first"] = {
  {name = "sammy", type = "dog", age = 2, color = "blue"},
  {name = "tom", type = "cat", age = 3, color = "orange"},
.
.
.
.
}

main["second"] = {
  {name = "grim", type = "cow", age = 1, color = "green"},
  {name = "jerry", type = "horse", age = 2, color = "grey"},
.
.
.
.
}
```

The table has two tables. I want to read all tables in main. So I wrote this code. (I use delphi. plua_state means pointer of lua_state)

*This is my code:*

```
procedure TForm1.PrintTable(l: Plua_State);
var
  TempStr : String;
begin
  lua_pushnil(l);

  TempStr := '';
  while lua_next(l,-2) <> 0 do
  begin
    case lua_type(l,-1) of
      LUA_TTABLE :
        PrintTable(l);

    else
      TempStr := TempStr + lual_checkstring(L, -2) + '='
                 + lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -1)) + ','; 
    end;
    lua_pop(l,1);
  end;

  fStringList.Add(TempStr);
end;
```

This code prints the key and value type in the main table.However, If I change `lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -1))` to `lual_checkstring(L, -1)`, It does not work. I want to print the key and value.

How can I print the value?

Comment: Thank you for your correction, Nolin M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be careful when using `lua_next` as several string API functions will alter the value on the stack which confuses `lua_next`. From the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_next):

> While traversing a table, do not call lua_tolstring directly on a key, unless you know that the key is actually a string. Recall that lua_tolstring may change the value at the given index; this confuses the next call to lua_next.

So, calling [lua_tostring](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_tostring), [lua_tolstring](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_tolstring), or [luaL_checklstring](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_checklstring) on a key pushed by `lua_next` will change the key into a string.

As you have discovered it is best to use `lua_type` to make sure the value is indeed a string before calling `lua_tolstring` (or any API function that calls it), or push a copy of the key which can be popped leaving the original key returned by `lua_next` unmodified.